# Removing red x in the last row of a datagridview image column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I tried to use the two following code samples and both remove the red x but causes an infinite loop when displaying. Once the cell is set to the AddNewIndex .bmp in RowPrePaint for some reason it calles RowPrePaint again. e is then 0 again and it keeps looping. Does anyone know of a way to set the value to the AddNewIndex .bmp without causing RowPrePaint to execute again? (Or a diffrent way to remove the red x?) Also just so I know next time, what is causing RowPrePaint to be called more then once?

```
    private void tableDocTypes_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= tableDocTypes.NewRowIndex)
            tableDocTypes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[columnDocTypeImage.Index].Value = Properties.Resources.AddNewIndex;
    }


    private void tableDocTypes_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (tableDocTypes.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) 
            tableDocTypes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[columnDocTypeImage.Index].Value = Properties.Resources.AddNewIndex;
    }
```

Also adding the following in the constructor:

```
        InitializeComponent();
        tableDocTypes.Columns[columnDocTypeImage.Index].DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = Properties.Resources.AddNewIndex;
```

Comment: Do you mean the "Broken Image" Red X?  If so, have you set the column to typeof(Byte[])?

Comment: Yes, this is the "Broken Image" Red X. How do I change the column to typeof(Byte[])?

Answer (score 0):

RowPrePaint fires when the row needs to be repainted. If you modify something in a row, that row needs to be repainted, recurse ad infinity.

I'm not entirely clear what it is that you're trying to accomplish, but my guess is that you want to alter what gets displayed for a particular cell. One of the best ways to do that is to handle the CellFormatting event. In that event, you alter the passed in `DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs.Value`, not the underlying data.

Comment: Thanks, using the CellFormating event works correctly now but once I click on the cell next to it the red x reappears. I think that is becasue I'm not actually changing the image in the DataGridView but rather just the value. If I try to change the DataGridView I get the same infinite loop issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are populating the DataGridView with a DataSet, add this code when creating the Table:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("ImageColumn");
dt.Columns["ImageColumn"].DataType = typeof(Byte[]);
```

Even if you're populating from a database, you can set this up before you add the data to the table.

Comment: I'm creating the DataGridView with the designer. I've never worked with DataTables before. Is there a way to change the DataType without creating a DataTable?

Comment: If you're creating all of the columns in the DataGridView in the Designer as well, then select the column, and change the ColumnType to DataGridViewImageBoxColumn.

Comment: Thats what its currently set to. And since it doesnt have an image in the last row it is displaying the red x.

Comment: So only some of the rows will have an image?

Comment: The whole first column with have images. Only the last row in the first column is blank becasue the column type is set to DataGridViewImageBoxColumn and the user can add rows. That is what is displaying the x.

Comment: Oh, yikes.  What about programmatically setting the Image on the last row to an empty image?

Comment: Just updated my comment. The best way to describe it is the last row in the first column is displaying the red x in one cell.

Comment: I took your advice and programmitcally set the image with tableDocTypes.Rows[tableDocTypes.NewRowIndex].Cells[columnDocTypeImage.Index].Value = Properties.Resources.AddNewIndex. Very simple compaired to what I was doing before. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Not a problem.  I hadn't done any of that kind of work with DataGridViews, though I have had images in there.  You got me to make a test app, and I was looking around in there.

Don't forget to test what happens when the new row gets created.  There is a NewRowNeeded event if the new row has that Broken Image.

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub DGV_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles DGV.CellPainting
    'get rid of that annoying red x
    If e.ColumnIndex = sender.Columns("ImageColumn").Index Then
        If e.RowIndex = sender.RowCount - 1 Then
            sender(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = Nothing
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Try the CellPainting code above to get rid of this very annoying and time-consuming bug.

Comment: This solution makes the image in my last row flicker uncontrollably.